# How to make query at laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have sql like this
SELECT no_po FROM `tpo_suppheader` WHERE no_po not in (
SELECT no_po FROM `tpo_supp_stok` ).

How to code at laravel?

```
 $datas = DB::table ('tpo_suppheader') 
            ->join('tpo_suppdetil', 'tpo_suppheader.no_po', '=', 'tpo_suppdetil.no_po')
            ->join('tmsupplier', 'tpo_suppheader.suppid', '=', 'tmsupplier.id')                    
            ->select('tpo_suppheader.*', 'tpo_suppdetil.*', 'tmsupplier.nama_supp')
            ->where('tpo_suppheader.no_po','like',"%".$var_cari."%")
            ->whereNotIn('no_po', $data_dtl)
            ->get();

 $datas = DB::table ('tpo_suppheader') 
            ->join('tpo_suppdetil', 'tpo_suppheader.no_po', '=', 'tpo_suppdetil.no_po')
            ->join('tmsupplier', 'tpo_suppheader.suppid', '=', 'tmsupplier.id')                    
            ->select('tpo_suppheader.*', 'tpo_suppdetil.*', 'tmsupplier.nama_supp')
            ->where('tpo_suppheader.no_po','like',"%".$var_cari."%")
            ->whereNotIn('no_po', $data_dtl)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for every query: use `toSql()` to know how the builder translates a query.

For example:

```php
dd(DB::table('table1')->...->toSql());
```

will dump the translated query. Tinker with this until you get the desired result. Using this method of trial and error, I got this:

```
$query = DB::table('tpo_suppheader')->select('no_po')             # SELECT no_po FROM tpo_suppheader
           ->whereNotIn('no_po', function ($subquery) {           # WHERE no_po NOT IN (
               $subquery->select('no_po')->from('tpo_supp_stok'); #     SELECT no_po FROM tpo_supp_stok
           });                                                    # )

dd($query->toSql());
#  "select "no_po" from "tpo_suppheader" where "no_po" not in (select "no_po" from "tpo_supp_stok")"

$results = $query->get();
```